# Let $\Sigma$ be the splitting field for $x^5 −7$ over $\Bbb Q$. How many roots of $x^4 +7x^3 +6x^2 +3x+3$ lie in $Σ$?

Tags: galois-theory

this is a question from my CW and I was confused on how to do this. I managed to find the splitting field and one of the roots of the polynomial, but I cant find the other roots and do not know how to tackle the question.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: From your **what**?

Comment: Coursework, perhaps? @DonAntonio

Comment: Maybe, @Shaun ....

Comment: I edited your post to make the $LaTeX$ render properly.  Cheers!

Comment: @Shaun Thank you, first time so didn't know.

Comment: @DonAntonio yes my coursework.

Comment: Do you know the degree of the splitting field?

Comment: @EricWofsey I believe its 20

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For any $a\in\Sigma$, the degree of the minimal polynomial of $a$ must divide $[\Sigma:\mathbb{Q}]=20$ (why?).  What possible minimal polynomials can roots of $x^4 +7x^3 +6x^2 +3x+3$ have?

Comment: so the min poly of degree 4,2 or 1 of the roots of $$x^4+7x^3+6x^2+3x+3$$